# Change the properties of a JPanel component through an action event

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, actionlistener

I'm trying to setup a system where when I press a button the JLabel text will change, but I can't seem to make it work. I've already tested that the action listener works by doing 'system.out.println("test");'. It works fine, but when trying to change a JComponent text it doesn't work. I've already searched for answers and found nothing that works.

Main class:

```java
package com.fcs.app;

public class A {
   public static void main(String args[]) {

    window w = new window();

    w.drawWindow();
   }
}
```

JFrame and JPanel class:

```java
package com.fcs.app;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class window extends JPanel {

JFrame jf = new JFrame();
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
JButton b1 = new JButton();
JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
JTextField tf2 = new JTextField();
JLabel plus = new JLabel();
JLabel equals = new JLabel();
JLabel rt = new JLabel();

int Result = 10;

public void drawWindow() {

    //JFrame setup
    jf.setSize(400, 400);
    jf.setUndecorated(true);
    jf.setLayout(null);
    jf.setContentPane(jp);
    jf.setLocation(100, 100);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setVisible(true);

    //JPanel setup
    jp.setSize(400, 400);
    jp.setLocation(0, 0);
    jp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    jp.add(b1);
    jp.add(tf1);
    jp.add(tf2);
    jp.add(plus);
    jp.add(equals);
    jp.add(rt);
    jp.setLayout(null);
    jp.setVisible(true);

    //JButton setup
    b1.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    b1.setText("Calculate!");
    b1.setSize(100, 40);
    b1.setLocation(150, 350);
    b1.addActionListener(new Listener());
    b1.setVisible(true);

    //TextField 1 setup
    tf1.setSize(120, 50);
    tf1.setLocation(140, 20);
    tf1.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    tf1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    tf1.setVisible(true);

    //TextField 2 setup
    tf2.setSize(120, 50);
    tf2.setLocation(140, 120);
    tf2.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    tf2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    tf2.setVisible(true);

    //Plus sign Setup
    plus.setSize(120, 50);
    plus.setLocation(140, 70);
    plus.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    plus.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    plus.setText("+");
    plus.setVisible(true);

    //Equals sign Setup
    equals.setSize(120, 50);
    equals.setLocation(140, 170);
    equals.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    equals.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    equals.setText("=");
    equals.setVisible(true);

    //Result text
    rt.setSize(400, 50);
    rt.setLocation(0, 250);
    rt.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    rt.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.PLAIN, 60));
    rt.setText("");
    rt.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

ActionListener class:

```java
package com.fcs.app;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Listener implements ActionListener {

window w = new window();

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    w.rt.setText("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: btw I'm still a beginner in java so I understand if this might seem like a dumb question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new references of Window like window w = new window();
it will create a new instance of window and you are trying to change newly created window.
Try to pass the window object you have created before in  window class or 
implement an anonymous ActionListener  in the window  class.

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    rt.setText("Test");
    }

}

});
```

Comment: how would i do that

Comment: i tried to put the action listener in the window class earlier and i got a bunch of errors so im not quite sure how i would go about doing that

Comment: implement the listener in window  class inside constructor method

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH... it worked. Sorry if my questioned seemed a bit noobish... but thanks for the help

Comment: damn do i feel like an idiot for not doing that in the first place XD

Comment: its ok, you are welcome buddy. even expert was once a beginner.